# Creating a single ARM binary for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, arm, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to see if it is possible to create using VS2013 a single binary that will work for both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 ARM devices.

I create a single Universal Apps project (under Visual C++ -> Store Apps -> Universal Apps) for a Windows Runtime Component.  When I build this, it generates two separate binaries – for Windows and Phone.

---

### Windows DLL

The linker inputs are runtimeobject.lib and kernel32.lib

Dump of file RuntimeComponent1.Windows\RuntimeComponent1.Windows.dll
  Image has the following dependencies:

```
vccorlib120_app.DLL
msvcp120_app.dll
msvcr120_app.dll
ole32.dll
api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll
KERNEL32.dll
```

---

### Windows Phone DLL

The linker inputs are WindowsPhoneCore.lib, RuntimeObject.lib and PhoneAppModelHost.lib

Dump of file RuntimeComponent1.WindowsPhone\RuntimeComponent1.WindowsPhone.dll
  Image has the following dependencies:

```
api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1.dll
vccorlib120_app.DLL
msvcp120_app.dll
msvcr120_app.dll
api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll
```

---

I believe all the dependencies in Phone can also be achieved for Windows also by using some other import libs other than kernel32.lib.  Is that right?  Is there any way of achieving this at all? i.e. creating a single ARM binary for Win8.1 and WP8.1?

### Update

I changed the settings of the Windows head to link to mincore.lib and specifically ignored kernel32.lib and ole32.lib.  Now, both Windows and Phone binaries get the same dependencies:

Windows:

```
vccorlib120_app.DLL
msvcp120_app.dll
msvcr120_app.dll
api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll
```

Windows Phone:

```
vccorlib120_app.DLL
msvcp120_app.dll
msvcr120_app.dll
api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll
```

However this is possible only for x86 since the Windows 8.1 SDK doesn't contain the import lib mincore.lib for ARM

Comment: You can with C# and PCL ;)

Comment: As soon as SQLite or OpenCV is implemented in C#, I will :)

Comment: Would this help with that goal -> https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: Not really.  What I really want to do is create a single native ARM binary.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get mincore.lib for ARM in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) for Windows 8.1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn249725%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It's installed in the Windows Kits folder like for Windows 10 SDKs.